# How to check if an input is empty using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input

Ok so I have an HTML input element

```
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
```

and in JavaScript I do :

```
var ninp = document.getElementById("name");
if(ninp.value == ""){
  do stuff
} else{
  do other stuff
}
```

Everytime I run the function it fires the "else" block of code I'm I doing something wrong or this isnt a correct way :/

Comment: It should be `if(ninp == "")` because you're already grabbing the `value` in the first line.

Comment: Oh exuse me that was a mistake the post is updated now

Comment: Is that the whole function because [that code works as it should](https://jsfiddle.net/zjbjxgeL/2/) (it's using the first condition, not the second).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first line of your code, you have gotten value of input tag. so you have something like this:

`ninp = "a string ..."`

and so it is impossible to have something like `ninp.value` in your condition in second line.

change

```
if(ninp.value == ""){
do stuff
}
```

to

```
if(ninp == ""){
 do stuff
}
```

Comment: The OP updated the question. This is no longer the case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something else in the function was breaking it but the answer was just to test for the length of the string

```
var ninpv = ninp.value;
if(ninpv.lenght == 0;){
do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check in this way

```
var ninp = document.getElementById("name").value;
if(ninp.length === 0){
  do stuff
} else {
  do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why do not you move to jquery and write

```
var ninp = $('#name');
if(ninp.val() =="")
{
//do stuff
}else
//otherstuff

or 
if(ninp.val().length==0)
```

Also keep it in mind if you are using JS form external files browser mostly do not load your updated js files. In this case I mostly use incognito mode of browser